# Generalize exception's handling Retrofit

Tags: android, design-patterns, retrofit, retrofit2

I have multiple API call in my Retrofit service and each methods are handling the same ugly Exceptions and checking the same attribute in the JSON response. I tried to make it more generic to reduce the size of each method but I don't know what's the best way to do it...   Here is two of many method that does pretty much the same things but with a different API call:

```
private void sendStopSecurityCheck() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(STOP_SECURITY_CHECK);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_FAILED);

    boolean isSuccess = connectAmazonApi();

    if(isSuccess){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = amazonServices.stopSecurityCheck(settings.getString("username", ""), settings.getString("orgid", ""));
        try {
            ResponseBody response = call.execute().body();
            JSONObject obj;
            if (response != null) {
                obj = new JSONObject(response.string());
                if(obj.getBoolean("success") == true){
                    intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_OK);
                }
                Log.w(TAG, "Result " + obj.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Amazon API");
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void sendConfirmSecurityCheck() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CONFIRM_SECURITY_CHECK);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_FAILED);

    boolean isSuccess = connectAmazonApi();

    if(isSuccess){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = amazonServices.confirmSecurityCheck(settings.getString("username", ""), settings.getString("orgid", ""));
        try {
            ResponseBody response = call.execute().body();
            JSONObject obj;
            if (response != null) {
                obj = new JSONObject(response.string());
                if(obj.getBoolean("success") == true){
                    intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_OK);
                }
                Log.w(TAG, "Result " + obj.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }else{
        Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Amazon API");
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: You can catch Exception, and you can create some object which handle this exception

Comment: You mean throw them and then catch them elsewhere?

Comment: try {
            ....
        } catch (Exception e) {
           ExceptionHandler.hanlde(e);
        }

Comment: I do it already no?

Comment: ExceptionHandler can be yours own object which will call code that you use many times

Comment: or you can create private method  which will handle your exception

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper Json parser like Gson? That would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Because I have already too many pojo for all the API call. Usually I do it, but for the use case where I only need to check if the request was a success, it think it would be overkill no?

Comment: I would call it overkill to manually parse Json for such a simple use case. Using a parser framework here will simplify your code, improve code clarity as well as quality and makes refactoring much simpler. You should never be afraid to create a new class. Having many small classes that serve exactly one purpose is a good thing.

Comment: @XaverKapeller  What do you mean by Parser framework? Do you have a link?

Comment: Something like Gson

Answer (score 1):

How about refactoring the code by extracting two methods?

One method to encapsulate the calling of synchronous requests and another to check if the synchronous request was successful or not.

```
private ResponseBody executeSynchronously(Call<ResponseBody> call) {
    try {
        return call.execute().body();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean parseResponse(ResponseBody response) {
    if (response == null) return false;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.string());
    try {
        Log.w(TAG, "Result " + obj.toString());
        return obj.getBoolean("success") == true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now refactor the `sendConfirmSecurityCheck` method as follows:

```
private void sendConfirmSecurityCheck() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CONFIRM_SECURITY_CHECK);
    intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_FAILED);

    boolean isSuccess = connectAmazonApi();

    if(isSuccess){
        Call<ResponseBody> call = amazonServices.confirmSecurityCheck(settings.getString("username", ""), settings.getString("orgid", ""));
        ResponseBody response = executeSynchronously(call);
        if (parseResponse(response)) {
            intent.putExtra(RESULT, RESULT_OK);
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Amazon API");
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```